# Python Exact Match- Absolute exact match

Tags: python

Based on the code I have I am trying to find an exact match to any of the job positions listed in the input.

INPUT

## this is str contains specific MATCH

```
dfp1[dfp1.index.str.match('Teacher|Dentist|General Manager|District Manager|Bus Driver|Team Lead|Dancer')]
```

Output is:

```
Teacher
Teacher, Middle
Teacher, High
Dentist, Sanford
Dentist
General Manager
General Manager, Dollar Tree
Team Lead
Dancer, 10th
Dancer
Dancer, Previous
```

I do not want anything extra other than the exact job position I put in the input.  I want to specifically see only Teacher or Dentist or General Manager or District Manager or Bus Driver or Team Lead or Dancer.

I am not sure what my code is missing for it to display the job titles and no others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is hard to understand. Please proofread your posts and take a look here to learn how to format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your regex. You need to add a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end.

```
dfp1[dfp1.index.str.match('^(Teacher|Dentist|General Manager|District Manager|Bus Driver|Team Lead|Dancer)$')]
```

Comment: awesome. it worked. Thanks so much. where did you learn that?

Comment: [Check this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Those elements are called anchors.